# Web.config. File not found when path is relative in httpErrors defaultPath section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I use custom error pages in my web application. For IIS i have these settings in web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File" defaultPath="404.html">
    <remove statusCode="500"/>
    <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

In this example i show 500.html file for error 500. For any other errors i show default 404.html file. Both files are in the root of application. if `defaultPath` is relative the file can not be found. But if i set absulute path then file can be shown. Like this:

```
defaultPath="c:\Code\MyApp\MyApp\404.html"
```

I want to point out that problem is actual exactly for `defaultPath` parameter. Relative path works perfectly in any other place in web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `defaultResponseMode` to `ExecuteURL`?

It appears that setting it to file tells IIS to expect a file path. ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497(v=vs.90).aspx))

Comment: defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" works fine, but i want to use static html files. It's not convenient to set absolute path

Comment: The documentation reads:  "If responseMode is set to ExecuteURL, the path value has to be a server relative URL." Are you having a problem using relative paths? They should work...